# PyTorch how to set the minimum value along each row of a tensor to zero?

Tags: indexing, pytorch, tensor

We don't know the shape of the input tensor and **we shouldn't use any loops**. Only **reduction and indexing operations**. How do we set the minimum value of each row to zero?

For example:

input:

```
x = torch.tensor([[
      [10, 20, 30]
      [2, 5, 1]
    ]])
```

output:

```
torch.tensor([
  [0, 20, 30],
  [2, 5, 0]
])
```

I couldn't figure it out and couldn't find any related questions. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do so is to compute row-wise minimum `x.min(dim=-1)`, get minimal values `x.min(dim=-1).values` (indices won't work in case of multiple minimal elements), get mask indicating locations of non-minimal elements using comparison and multiply by it:

```py
axis = -1  # Minimum iterating over the last dimension
min_values = x.min(dim=axis).values  # Get minimal values
min_values_shape_corrected = min_values.unsqueeze(axis)  # Reshape the minimal values so we can compare it with `x`
mask = (x != min_values_shape_corrected)  # Get the mask of non-minimal elements
result = x * mask  # Multiplying by a boolean mask leaves only True elements and sets False ones to 0
```

Or in one line

```py
x * (x != x.min(dim=axis).values.unsqueeze(axis))
```